# How to move up or down a text row in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm facing a the problem about move up or move down a text row, when I move up or down a row, it can move but seem old row is still exist and was not deleted
[image]

for example: 
I move down 'text 2', it can move but row is still exist

this is my sources:

```
<head>
<script>
function down_move(index)
{
var frm = document.writeForm;
var opts=frm["ans_list" + index].options

for (var i=opts.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (opts[i].selected && i<opts.length-1) {
        tmp = opts[i].cloneNode(true);
        // opts[i].removeChild(true);
        opts[i].removeChild(opts[i].childNodes[0]);
        opts[i].insertAdjacentElement("afterEnd", tmp).selected = true;
    }
}
 setting_val(index);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
   <a href="#" onClick="javasript:down_move('<%=i+1%>');" style="float:left"><span class="bt_test_admin bg_type_01">▼ Order</span></a>
</div>
</body>
```

I get a message from console bug browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

How to fix the error? thanks

Comment: Can you please update your question to include a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Thanks.

Comment: When you say "text row", do you mean an `<option>` element within a `<select>` element? The HTML shown doesn't include any `ans_listx` element, so please [edit] your question to provide all of the relevant HTML.

Comment: Hi @nnnnnn: it just a normal row with text

Comment: *"it just a normal row with text"* - What is a "normal row"? `<table>` elements have rows, but your JavaScript is doing something to an element with an `.options` collection, which implies a `<select>` element. Again, please [edit] the question to show the relevant HTML.

Comment: Sorry because I just focus on row to move it, I will update my question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is lacking HTML context. Anyway, removing option from select seems to be wrong

I changed your code like this.

```
function down_move(index)
{
var frm = document.writeForm;
var elSelect = frm["ans_list" + index];
var opts=elSelect.options

for (var i=opts.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (opts[i].selected && i<opts.length-1) {
        tmp = opts[i].cloneNode(true);
        tmp.selected=true;
        // opts[i].removeChild(true);
        elSelect.remove(i);
        elSelect.add(tmp, i + 1);
    }
}
 setting_val(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the parent **tr** of the button and then find the element to which append before. Because of there is no function for append after one element you have to find the second next element when you want to move down.

Just apply this both function on row up and row down respectively.I am sure it will work for you

**Move Up function**

```
function MoveUpRow() {
    var table,
        row = this.parentNode;

    // find the parent tr ( the row element )
    while ( row != null ) {
        if ( row.nodeName == 'TR' ) {
            break;
        }
        row = row.parentNode;
    }
    // the parent of the row is the table body
    table = row.parentNode;
    // insert the row before it's previevs siblings
    table.insertBefore ( row, get_previoussibling( row ) );
}
```

**Move Down Row Function**

```
function MoveDownRow() {
    var table,
        row = this.parentNode;

    while ( row != null ) {
        if ( row.nodeName == 'TR' ) {
            break;
        }
        row = row.parentNode;
    }
    table = row.parentNode;
    // you have to find the second next siblings to append before
    // NOTE: if the second parameter of the 'insertBefore' function is null
    //       it will append the row to the table! 
    table.insertBefore ( row, get_nextsibling ( get_nextsibling( row ) ) );
}
```