# How to move up a selected row in Javascript on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using javascript to move up a selected row, but when I move up, it seem can move but old row is still exist.

for example: 
 I move up 'bbbb' row, it can move up but old row is not still removed

[image]

this is my sources:

```
function up_move(index)
{
var frm = document.writeForm;
var opts=frm["ans_list" + index].options

for (var i=0; i<opts.length; i++) {
    if (opts[i].selected && i>0) {          
        tmp=opts[i].cloneNode(true);
        // opts[i].removeChild(true);
        opts[i].removeChild(opts[i].childNodes[0]);
        opts[i-1].insertAdjacentElement("beforeBegin",tmp).selected=true;            
    }
}

setting_val(index); 
}

<tr>
   <td><a href="#" onClick="javasript:up_move('<%=i+1%>');" style="float:left"><span class="bt_test_admin bg_type_01">▲ Up</span></a></td>
</tr>
```

How to fix this error? Thanks so much !

Comment: Isn't this basically the same problem as [your own question five days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556064/how-to-move-up-or-down-a-text-row-in-javascript)?

Comment: Yes, it same. Because I have to change something for my project, so I have to update my question a little...

Comment: Sorry for this...

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery, no need to clone and remove, you can use `.insertBefore()` and `.insertAfter()` function.

**HTML:**

```
<select size="5">
  <option>aaaa</option>
  <option>bbbb</option>
  <option>cccc</option>
  <option>dddd</option>
</select>

<button id="btn_up">up</button>
<button id="btn_down">down</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn_up').on('click',function() {
        var sel = $('select option:selected');
        if (!sel.is(':first')) {
            sel.insertBefore(sel.prev());
        }
    });
    $('#btn_down').on('click',function() {
        var sel = $('select option:selected');
        if (!sel.is(':last')) {
            sel.insertAfter(sel.next());
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: **https://www.bootply.com/x2cUA8SEMQ**

## Alternative:

based on your request, with `<a href>`

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:up_move();" style="float:left"><span class="bt_test_admin bg_type_01">▲ Up</span></a>
<br>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:down_move();" style="float:left"><span class="bt_test_admin bg_type_01">Down</span></a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function up_move() {
    var sel = $('select option:selected');
    if (!sel.is(':first')) {
        sel.insertBefore(sel.prev());
    }
}
function down_move() {
    var sel = $('select option:selected');
    if (!sel.is(':last')) {
        sel.insertAfter(sel.next());
    }
}
```

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/sbv6stqh/**

Comment: @luongkhanh `<a href="..."></a>`? I don't understand, do you want to redirect page in each "up" and "down" click?

Comment: because my source use 'onClick' and param: '<%=i+1%>' and how to use it when change to jquery..

Comment: @luongkhanh I see, of course you can. Just have to modify my script above. I'll try to update my answer based of your need. Wait.

Comment: @luongkhanh yes, I've updated my answer, I added alternative way. See above and try it.